# What transformations does a macro's text undergo before it is saved to memory?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I've noticed that TeX doesn't always save a macro's text as typed. For instance, the following plain TeX manuscript:

```
\def\a#1{\relax#1}%
\font\myfont=cmtt12\myfont%
\meaning\a%
\bye
```

produces the output

> macro:#1->\relax #1

Note that the output shows a space between '\relax' and '#1' where none exists in the manuscript. This discrepancy can have a dramatic effect on the execution of the manuscript.

Consider, for instance, the following manuscript.

```
\def\a#1{\def\b#1{Hello, world!}}%
\a c%
\bc%
\bye
```

If `\a`'s text were saved as-is, this manuscript would compile successfully, the second line would define the macro `\bc`, and the third line would output: `Hello, world!`. Instead, the compilation aborts with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \bc
```

It therefore behooves to know: what transformations exactly does a macro's text undergo before it is saved to memory?

Comment: what do you mean by "manuscript"?

Comment: @erreka: A program written in the TeX language. This is the terminology used in the TeXbook by the creator of TeX.

Comment: I suspect you are taking a Knuthian way of saying as something normative or even mandatory, along the lines of [one of your other questions](http://bit.ly/2vH87IR). A "manuscript" (or more precisely, a "typescript" for a computer document), in common parlance, as you probably know, is the general term for the original of your document. In TeX's case, as in many a text with markup, has text interspersed with code/markup. In your example you are not marking up any text, so strictly speaking it is only "code".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically: What TeX stores is not text (sequence of characters) but tokens: after your `\def` it remembers that the definition of `\a` has the control sequence `\relax` followed by macro parameter 1, and when you ask for this token list to be printed, it *shows* you a space after the `\relax` token, just for clarity.

I'm not sure about the “user”-level description of this as described in *The TeXbook* etc., but I can point you to the “internal” representation as described in *TeX: The Program*. See Part 20 (Token Lists) of `texdoc tex`. A token is either a `(command code, character)` pair, or a control sequence. With that background:

- The `\def` you type gets stored as a sequence of tokens:

[image: part 1]

- Then the above token list, when you ask for the definition of `\mac` to be shown, gets shown as:

[image: part 2]

(In this example the text happens to be identical, but note that you could have left out the space after the `\b` in the input text, and the internal token list representation would have been the same, so you would still have a space after the `\b` if you asked for it to be printed.)

Comment: Thanks. This was illuminating. However, I'm still left wondering: why, then, does the following manuscript: `\def\a#1{\def\b#1{Hello, world!}}\a c\bc\bye` results in an error (`! Undefined control sequence. l.3 \bc`)? I'd expect it to output: `Hello, world!`.

Comment: I've added the contents of my comment to my question.

Comment: @EvanAad Your input definition becomes `\def\b c{...}` so whenever you invoke `\b` it looks for a `c` to parse its input. `\b c` would work but `\b` won't

Comment: @percusse: This would make sense, except how do you deduce from ShreevatsaR's answer that my input definition becomes `\def\b c{...}`?

Comment: @EvanAad Maybe you should wait a bit longer before accepting answers. :-) Anyway, from a close look at the example above I can deduce that after `\def\a#1{\def\b#1{Hello, world!}}`, the definition of `\a` is stored as the token list (match `#`, end_match, `\def`, `\b`, out_param 1, `{`, letter `h`, … etc., so that when TeX expands `\a c`, these two tokens get replaced by the token list `\def`, `\b`, letter `c`, `{`, … etc. You can deduce from here what the result of expanding `\def` operating on that stream of tokens will be.

Answer (score 6):

The code

```
\def\a#1{\def\b#1{Hello, world!}}%
\a c%
\bc%
```

defines `\a` with one parameter; upon calling `\a c`, `#1` becomes `c`, so what's executed is

```
\def•\b•c•{•H•e•l•l•o•,• •w•o•r•l•d•!•}
```

which defines `\b` with parameter text `c` and replacement text `Hello, world!`. (`•` is used here to separate tokens, for better clarity.)

If you do `\show\a`, you get

```
> \a=macro:
#1->\def \b #1{Hello, world!}.
```

which uses a different representation (a space after a control word), but this amounts to exactly the same thing: `\b` has already been tokenized. If you want to define `\bc`, you need

```
\def\a#1{\expandafter\def\csname b#1\endcsname{Hello, world!}}
```

Now `\a c` will define `\bc` to have replacement text `Hello, world!`.

---

As said before, the representation with `\show` or `\meaning` adds a space after control words, which is unconsequential if you copy and paste the shown code, as spaces are ignored in that position. This way you can *see* the division into tokens. Of course, it's possible to be misguided if something strange is done:

```
\catcode`z=12
\def\a#1{\def\z#1{Hello, world!}}
\show\a
```

would display

```
> \a=macro:
#1->\def \z#1{Hello, world!}.
```

but `\a c` would *not* define a macro `\zc`, because `#1` is still a separate *parameter token*.

*No* transformation whatsoever is done to the tokens during `\def`, except for tokenization (which fixes category codes, by the way).

The category code of the characters forming the name of a macro are not recorded in any way. However, TeX will add a space in the `\show`/`\meaning` representation only after control words, not control symbols. So if you add

```
\catcode`z=11
\show\a
```

to the code above, the second `\show` will output

```
> \a=macro:
#1->\def \z #1{Hello, world!}.
```

because at this point, `\z` is to be considered a control word. This has more to do with input from a `.tex` file, rather than with tokens: always remember that already stored tokens are not touched by category code changes, but input ones are.

A real world example is the LaTeX macro `\@`. In code where the category code of `@` is 11 (which is frequently done for defining “private” macros), `\@` still has the same definition as when `@` has category code 12. However, care is needed when *using* `\@` in code, because

```
\@x
```

is read in as two tokens in normal situations (catcode of `@` is 12), but just one when the catcode of `@` is 11. Not a big deal, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks. The words "`\b` has already been tokenized" were the key to my understanding of this part of my question.

Comment: Can you please explain your last example? What did changing `z`'s catcode accomplish? Does the inner macro have an empty name? If not, what is the inner macro's name? Why didn't `\show\a` add a space between `\z` and `#1` in the console output? Why would `\a c` not define a macro `\zc`?

Comment: @EvanAad In the representation by `\show`, a control symbol is not followed by a space, but this has no other consequence, as `\z` has already been tokenized as ***one*** token and `#1` is a parameter token, representing the argument (as a sequence of tokens) at macro call.

Comment: Thanks. Just let me understand, is the following statement correct? A macro's name is either a non-empty string of catcode-11 tokens, or a single catcode-12 token, and the catcodes of the tokens that make up the name are saved with the macro.

Comment: @EvanAad No, the catcodes of the tokens that make up the name are *not* saved with the macro.

Comment: But if `z`'s catcode isn't saved with the macro, then the macro you defined has the exact same internal representation if you comment-out the first line (`cathode\`z=12`). However if you do so, the console output shows a space between the `\z` and the `#1`.

Comment: @EvanAad I see no space between `\z` and `#1` in the `\show` output. Of course, if you change back the category code of `z` to 11, `\z` becomes a normal control word, exactly because category codes of characters forming the name are not saved. So long as the catcode of `z` remains 12, `\z` is a control symbol (with the relative rules for tokenization); if it becomes 11 again, `\z` is a control word.

Comment: This was my point! If `z`'s catcode is not saved with the macro, then why do the outputs differ when you change `z`'s catcode?

Comment: @EvanAad Because `z` still has category code 12 at the point of `\show` and TeX doesn't add a space after a control symbol in the *output* of `\show` or `\meaning`. The key is the category code at the point of `\show`.