# A macro defined with \edef, whose body consists solely of non-expandable tokens

Tags: tex-core

The following plain TeX code is modeled after a similar line of code in the pgf/tikz source code (near the end of the the `\pgfoo@inherit@methods` macro in `<pgf/tikz installation dir>/modules/pgfmoduleoo.code.tex`):

```
\edef\c{%
    \noexpand\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname a\endcsname%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname b\endcsname%
%}
```

When I print `\c`'s `\meaning` I get:

```
macro:->\let \a \b
```

This is not what I expect. What I expect is

```
macro:->\noexpand \let \expandafter \noexpand ... \csname b\endcsname
```

In other words, I expect the exact same list of tokens as was used to define `\c`. The reason for this expectation is that `\edef` is supposed to expand only macros, but none of the tokens in `\c`'s definition is a macro.

Why is `\c`'s `\meaning` the way it is?

Comment: `\noexpand`, `\csname` and `\expandafter` *are* expandable

Comment: @egreg: So what is the definition of an expandable token? Why is `\noexpand` expandable, but `\let` isn't? How can I tell?

Comment: From the TeX source. obligatory read --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12482

Comment: Any expandable token is expandable, the others aren't. `;-)` The TeXbook lists all expandable primitives.

Comment: BTW, "expandable" is a really poor name: it *sounds* like "can be expanded", but rather it means "will be expanded (usually)". That is, an expandable token is something such that, when TeX encounters it as it passes through its input stream of tokens, it calls an internal `expand` function. (In the normal case, though things like `\expandafter` can alter this behaviour.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I really enjoyed and felt that my eyes were opened by [your answer to my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386632/21685), where you quoted from the TeX source code. Is there any chance you could give a similar answer to this question. I'd love to understand this from an implementation point of view.

Comment: I don't think there's anything much to say beyond what egreg said...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros, that is tokens defined with `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` or `\xdef` are expandable. Every token `\let` to an expandable token is expandable.

Primitives can be expandable; the expandable primitives are

- `\csname`
- `\else`
- `\expandafter`
- `\fi`
- `\if...` (any primitive conditional)
- `\input`
- `\meaning`
- `\noexpand`
- `\number`
- `\or`
- `\romannumeral`
- `\string`
- `\the`

e-TeX adds some more conditionals and the expandable primitives

- `\detokenize`
- `\eTeXrevision`
- `\scantokens`
- `\unexpanded`
- `\unless`

Note that e-TeX also adds `\protected`; a macro defined with `\protected\def` will not be expanded in the general texts for `\edef` or `\write`.

The `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex` engines add more expandable primitives; check their documentation.

In the code you write, the first `\noexpand` does nothing at all. Indeed, the role of `\noexpand` is to make the following token equivalent to `\relax` at the next usage (hence unexpandable); the expansion of `\noexpand` is empty, after having performed its duty. However, `\let` is not expandable to begin with, so it isn't touched during `\edef`.

Similarly, `\expandafter` expands to nothing after having expanded the token after the following one (if expandable at all).

Therefore the code in your `\edef\c`  becomes, in turn,

```
\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname a\endcsname\expandafter\noexpand\csname b\endcsname
```

(`\let` is equivalent to `\relax`)

```
\let\noexpand\a\expandafter\noexpand\csname b\endcsname

\let\a\noexpand\b
```

(`\a` is equivalent to `\relax`)

```
\let\a\b
```

(`\b` is equivalent to `\relax`)

When `\c` is expanded, `\let` `\a` and `\b` are not equivalent to `\relax` any longer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also explain why `\edef\c{\let\a\b}` is not equivalent to the original expression, and produces an error, even when `\b` is defined?

Comment: @EvanAad because `\a` and `\b` would get expanded inside `\edef`.

Comment: …provided, of course, that they are expandable, and not be `\let`  equal to unexpandable tokens (addition to @Skillmon’s comment)

Comment: Since you gave a non-exhaustive list of expandable control-sequences, could you please complement it with a list of some popular non-expandable control-sequences?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. An assignment of a value to a register is not expandable, right? Nor is `\relax`?

Comment: @EvanAad That's the complete list (except for mark related commands). Assignments are not made by expansion.

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean by "mark related commands"?

Comment: @EvanAad See Chapter 23 of the TeXbook, pages 258–259.

Answer (score 4):

OK, as requested, here is a run-through of what happens in the TeX program, in the case of `\def` and `\edef` respectively. For this question it adds absolutely nothing over the basic point (that `\noexpand`, `\expandafter` etc. are indeed “expandable”), but it may be interesting to you anyway.

You will want to refer to the [TeX program](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf) as you read the following.

What TeX's `main_control` procedure (section 1030) does is to read a token (`get_x_token`) in (essentially) a loop, and decide what to do. The inner loop is tightly optimized for regular characters in horizontal mode, but things like `\hrule` or `\def` are not part of it (→ section 1045), and in fact `\def` and `\edef` are part of mode-independent processing (→ section 1210), and result in a call to the procedure `prefixed_command` (section 1211). This procedure is common to many primitives/commands, but for both `\def` and `\edef`, it is called with:

- `cur_cmd` = [a code indicating "def"], and
- `cur_chr` = [0 for `\def`, 1 for `\gdef`, 2 for `\edef`, 3 for `\xdef`]

(As you may guess from these four numbers, Knuth later checks "`odd(cur_chr)`" to decide whether the current definition should be global or not, and "`e = (cur_chr >= 2)`" to decide whether to expand or not!)

Anyway, in this `prefixed_command` procedure (section 1211), the execution falls into section 1217 then 1218, which is:

[image: §1218 def]

Suppose your input had `\def\foo{\bar}` or `\edef\foo{\bar}`. Then in the above, `get_r_token; p ← cur_cs;` would set `p` to (basically) `\foo`, and then `scan_toks(true, e)` is called.

Here, of the two parameters to `scan_toks`, the first one (`macro_def`, here passed as `true`) says that the token list to be scanned is that for a macro definition (as opposed to the token list for a `\mark`, `\output`, `\message`, `\everypar`, etc.), and the second boolean (`xpand`, here passed as `e`) decides whether to expand or not.

So let's dive into `scan_toks` (section 473).

[image: §473 <code>scan_toks</code>]

First, as we're in `macro_def`, it goes into `⟨Scan and build the parameter part of the macro definition⟩`, section 474. In our example (parameterless macro), all that happens is that `get_token` gets token begin-group character `{`, and therefore this part simply ends with `end_match_token` being added to the token list. The token list for the actual body of the definition is scanned in section 477.

This one basically gets tokens one-by-one and adds them to the token list being built (for the body of the definition), with the crucial difference that in the case of `\edef` or `\xdef`, the tokens get expanded as we go along:

[image: § 477 scan body token list]

- In the case of `\def\foo{\bar}` there is no complication of expansion and this part of the token list contains basically just the token `\bar`; so after `scan_toks` returns, the definition of `\foo` is saved as the token list containing [two tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386628/what-transformations-does-a-macros-text-undergo-before-it-is-saved-to-memory/386632#386632), `end_match` and `\bar`.
- In the case of `\edef\foo{\bar}`, this part (remember we're still inside `scan_toks`) reads tokens from the input stream (currently containing `\bar`) one at a time, each time expanding any token it sees. Specifically, the expansion here happens in section 478's call to the procedure `expand` (section 366). The way this procedure works is that each time it is called, it (essentially) simply destroys the first token in the input stream, and replaces it with the “expansion” (whatever is appropriate) of the removed token. This way, the next calls to `get_token` (say) will pick up the replaced tokens.

As you can see, here “expand” / “expansion” / “expandable” means basically anything that has a replacement (i.e. should be changed somehow), which does not mean only macros, and includes things like `\noexpand` and `\expandafter`:

[image: § 366, expand, part 1]
[image: § 366, expand, part 2]
[image: § 366, expand, part 3]

(Don't try to directly infer the expandable TeX primitives from the names of the variables code; instead see egreg's answer. For example, the primitives `\number`, `\romannumeral`, `\string`, `\meaning`, `\fontname`, `\jobname` are all expandable, because they all result in the command code `convert` that is in the list in the code above.)

Comment: Thanks. It's so helpful to have a guided look under the hood at the actual implementation. Do you get all this by simply reading the source-code, or do you also have access to a debugger for the TeX program, so you can set breakpoints and watch the values of internal variables during runtime?

Comment: @EvanAad This was all newly gained and hard-won knowledge :-) I built TeX Live's `tex` from source with [`-g`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and then the binaries without `strip`, then stepped through the program execution in `gdb`. The source code generated by web2c is quite hard to read. For example where the woven WEB program (as in screenshots above) contains “ **if** *every_job ≠ null* **then** *begin_token_list(every_job, every_job_text)*; ”, the C code contains `if ( eqtb [25064 ].hh .v.RH != -268435455L ) begintokenlist ( eqtb [25064 ].hh .v.RH , 12 ) ;`

Comment: … so I haven't yet figured out the equivalent of watching internal variables. But even though the code is rather different, with both the woven TeX program (`texdoc tex`) and the source code open, there are enough clues to manually (with some pattern-matching) follow execution in terms of the readable TeX program, by seeing which instructions are getting executed in the less-readable C program. What a function returned or what a token list contains is just inference/guess currently, but perhaps one can write some gdb helper utilities to print out variables in a readable form if type is known.

Comment: What do you mean by "... and then the binaries without `strip`"? If you'd already built `tex` from source, why couldn't you just use the binaries generated by this build?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes you are right; it's just that the `Build` script distributed with texlive immediately runs `strip` after generating the binaries. So you have to make sure that step doesn't run (or you use the binaries from before that step); that's all I meant. (See [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/build.html) and [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html).) BTW if you'd like to try it yourself, note that you need about 7.5 GB.