# Is \string expandable?

Tags: tex-core

I read the following sentence in *TeX by Topic* by Victor Eijkhout, in page 50:

The `\string` command is executed by the expansion processor, thus it is expanded unless explicitly inhibited.

Does it mean `\string` is expandable? But I use `\meaning\string`, and it only turns out `\string`. So what does it mean?

Comment: Related: [Why isn't everything expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable)

Comment: [list of expandable primitives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386741/a-macro-defined-with-edef-whose-body-consists-solely-of-non-expandable-tokens/386745#386745)

Answer (score 13):

To find out whether something is expandable, slap it into an `\edef` and see what happens.  Here we can for example do

```
\edef\test{\string\relax}
\show\test
```

Then in the terminal we see

```
> \test=macro:
->\relax.
```

Now `\string` is gone and the definition of `\test` is now just `\12r12e12l12a12x12` where all the tokens have catcode 12 as indicated by the subscript, which is exactly the effect `\string` should have.

So yes, `\string` is expandable.

---

To answer the other part, when you use `\show` on a control sequence and you get something like

```
> \string=\string.
```

that means that this control sequence is a *primitive*.

Comment: Unhappily, the terminal or the `.log` file do not show any category codes. If `\string` would result in the token `\relax` it would severely damage its expandability. At least a missing space in the terminal tells that `\relax` is *not* the token `\relax`.

Comment: The fact that `\string` doesn’t appear in the meaning of `\test` is by itself a sign that `\string` is expandable.

Comment: @egreg That's the nature of a macro. With `\edef\test{\string\string}`, the tokens `\string` appear in the meaning of `\test`. I think, the more interesting test is, whether the macro survives a `\csname ...\endcsname` (without calling the closing `\endcsname`). When it survives, the macro can be used in `\label`, bookmarks, ...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek a delimited macro could gobble all up to `\endcsname`, leave `empty\endcsname` and then do non-expandable things. (this is not quite the same `\endcsname` `;-)` hence my comment...)

Answer (score 4):

With an interactive session.

```
> tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\message{\string\relax}
\relax
*\message{\relax}
\relax 
*\bye
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

The fact that `\message{\string\relax}` only prints `\relax` means that `\string` is expandable, because unexpandable tokens are written as themselves by a `\message`, like in the example with `\message{\relax}`.

By the way, inputting `\message{\string}` will print nothing on the console, because `\string` has performed its duty and stringified `}`, so the text for `\message` is unfinished. Typing in another `}` will end the loop and print `}`.

```
> tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\message{\string}

*}
} 
*\bye
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Comment: perhaps add a note that `\message` does not behave versus braces like would macro definitions or for that matter expansion of user `\def`-ined macros

Comment: @jfbu Did you try `\edef\rbracestring{\string}}`? Well, `\message` behaves like `\edef`.

Comment: I referred to `\def` not `\edef`... but +1 for mentioning your point.

Comment: @jfbu Actually, they behave exactly the same; the point is that in the `\edef` TeX doesn't see the first `}` as a group close token, but as a catcode 12 character, because `\string` has been expanded. Instead, `\def\foo{\string}}` would be illegal because the first `}` still has category code 2.

Comment: well `\def\bar{\def\foo{\string}}` is legal...

Comment: @jfbu But doing `\bar` would not define `\foo` to a category code 12 `}`.

Comment: @jfbu: See also _The TeXbook_, exercise 20.17.

Answer (score 1):

My biased grain of salt is that for expandable coding, the criterion will be more whether `\string` behaves well in an `\if` or `\ifnum` test, or in a `\numexpr`. Thus,

```
\ifnum\string1=1
```

not raising an error is good validation for me, because it means (suggests, rather...) I will be able to use such constructs in expandable coding.

That it expands fully in an `\edef` is less interesting, because I can not use `\edef` inside an expandable macro.

The `\csname...\endcsname` is more in the `\ifnum` category, from that point of view.