# Spaces added in the argument of a command

Tags: tex-core

Consider the MWE example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\toot#1{%
   \def\content{#1}%
   \meaning\content%
}
\toot{\textsc{1}}

s


\end{document}
```

Why the result of `\meaning\toto` is `\toot{\textsc {1}}` and not `\toot{\textsc{1}}`  (that have an impact on [Reledmac/Reledmac: duplicating index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420502)

Comment: That’s a hardwired feature of TeX: a space always follows a control word in TeX’s internal representation.

Comment: Did you mean `\meaning\toot` instead of `\meaning\toto`?

Comment: Is the problem that you need to write `\textsc{1}` to an external file (rather than using it at that point in the document)? In which case, are you able to just do `\string\textsc`?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot unfortunatly not, because \toot is (in reality) a user level command of reledmac (\Aendnote). So I can't ask to use \string.

Comment: @Maïeul Okay. Thought it worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Related question: [What transformations does a macro's text undergo before it is saved to memory?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386628/what-transformations-does-a-macros-text-undergo-before-it-is-saved-to-memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX does not save character strings in its memory but tokens. When the parameter of `\toot` in the line of your example

```
\toot{\textsc{1}}
```

is scanned, the tokenizer creates the tokens "textsc", "{", "1" and "}". When TeX is asked to print the tokens (using `\meaning` in your example) then it must solve the question how tokens of control-sequence type are printed. If the printed token control sequence name consists of letters then TeX prints a backslash in front of and a space after such token. This is decision of TeX’s author. The reason: the tokens "relax", "a" are printed as `\relax a` which is better than `\relaxa`.

**Edit** If you want to elaborate with catcodes, then an example follows. The parameter of the `\toot` macro is read (and tokenized) when catcodes of backslash and space are 12 (normal). So you can detect duplicate spaces and there are no control sequences. As soon as the parameter is read, the standard catcodes are set back (at `\egroup`). Then a second "normal" variant of the parameter is prepared using `\scantokens` because we expect that macro programmer needs to manipulate with both variants: "normal" and "space-respected". Finally the macro `\tootB` is started. It gets two parameters, first is "normal" variant of parameter and second is "space-respected" variant (where no control sequences are).

```
\def\toot{\bgroup \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\ =12 \tootA}

\long\def\tootA#1{\egroup
   \scantokens{\def\tmp{#1}}%
   \expandafter\tootB\expandafter{\tmp}{#1}%
}
\long\def\tootB#1#2{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \message{normal: "\meaning\tmp"}
  \def\tmp{#2}%
  \message{space-respected: "\meaning\tmp"}
}

\toot{\textsc{1}}

\toot{\textsc{ a b   c \par a\par1 \textbf {a}a}}

\toot{\textsc{ a b c \hskip1em a\space 1 \textbf {a}a}}

\bye
```

Comment: thank. So no workaround?

Comment: More precisely, in front of a control sequence the character with character code `\escapechar` is added (nothing if `\escapechar` is outside the range of character codes). There is no provision for an “after control word character” which is always a space character (charcode 32, catcode 10).

Comment: No workaround. The information if the space were typed or no is lost at tokenizer phase. You cannot know about it at expand processor. Only workaround: change catcode of the space when the parameter of `\toot` is read. I can show it, but catcode changing (especially of space) is very fragile.

Answer (score 2):

With a macro which eats every space following a control sequence (so a macro name which consists of only alphabetic characters) which is not followed by an alphabetic character in its (once) expanded argument you can get what you want. It also eats the space if you typed it yourself, though.

**EDIT:** One could read the argument to the macro verbatim and then replace everything which should have been a macro with the macro. As a result `\toottwo` can't be used inside of an argument of another macro.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_maieul_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \eatmacrospace { m }
  {
    \tl_set:No \l_maieul_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { (\\[A-Za-z]+)\s([^A-Za-z]) } { \1\2 } \l_maieul_tl
    \l_maieul_tl
  }
\str_new:N \l_maieul_str
\int_new:N \l_maieul_int
\NewDocumentCommand \toottwo { +v }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_maieul_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \\([A-Za-z]+) } { \c{\1} } \l_maieul_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \\([^A-Za-z]) } { \c{\1} } \l_maieul_tl
    \exp_args:NnV \regex_count:nnN { \{ } \l_maieul_tl \l_maieul_int
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { \c_one } { \c_one } { \l_maieul_int }
      {
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cO{(.*)\cO} } { \cB{\1\cE} } \l_maieul_tl
      }
    %\tl_show_analysis:N \l_maieul_tl % for debugging
    \let\content\l_maieul_tl
    \str_set:Nn \l_maieul_str { #1 }
    \texttt{macro:->\l_maieul_str}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\long\def\toot#1{%
   \def\content{#1}%
   \texttt{\meaning\content}\\%
   \texttt{\eatmacrospace{\meaning\content}}%
}
\begin{document}
\toot{\textsc{1}}

\toot{\textsc{ a b c \par a\par1 \textbf {a}a}}

\toottwo{\textsc{ a b c \hskip1em a\space 1 \textbf {a}a}}

\content% content is expandable

s


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank. Unfortunetaly, in real word, it nos everxtime the first space !

Comment: @Maïeul I know and am working on it :)

Comment: @Maïeul see my edit.

Comment: Your example clearly shows that there is no solution. When input inludes `\par1 \textbf {}` then you cannot restore this string because you have `\par 1 \textbf {}` XOR `\par1 \textbf{}`.

Comment: @wipet yes, it just shows that. It just converts the TeX internal representation in the equivalent form without spaces following control sequences when not necessary.

Comment: @wipet one could read the argument verbatim and turn it back to executable macros (see my edit) :)

Comment: @Skillmon yes, the catcode dance can be done. I'v put an example of such catcode experiment (see my Edit). Of course, I didn't use expl3:).

Comment: @wipet well done! I tend to use `expl3` in those cases because it is just easier to read, understand, and write. Also I'm still a TeXpert I guess, not a TeXnician yet.